# (International / UK / US) RÖMERTOPF equivalents?

Tags: equipment

I have a [RÖMERTOPF](http://www.roemertopf.de/english/) at home. It is a porous clay casserole dish.

I have recipes, sure. But I'm always looking for more. I'm not asking for recipes, though: I'm asking what the closest international / UK / US equivalents would be, so that I could be sure that I find appropriate recipes when looking for it.

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of this.  That looks really cool!

Comment: Agreed, I may just have to find for my next kitchen purchase!  They look very reasonably priced for their size, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is really a US equivalent, but a Moroccan tagine would be close.

Comment: I thought tagine's were always glazed - but apparently, that's not so! Tx. for that.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen terra cotta casserole dishes. You could also re-purpose a flower pot, although I'm not sure if you could find something in the correct shape (or with a lid).

Comment: Alton Brown makes a smoker out of two terra cotta flower pots in one of his episodes, he also had a hard time finding a lid but just used a second pot upside-down.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ka2kpzTAL8

Answer (score 1):

Pampered Chef sells a line of [unglazed stoneware](http://www.pamperedchef.com/our_products/catalog/overview.jsp?categoryCode=FH), but I don't believe that any of their stuff has lids, so it's not quite the same as what you have.

The only issue that I'm aware of is that you have to preheat the pan with the whole oven, or you risk the thermal shock from going into a hot oven causing cracking, so it's likely that you'll have to adjust your recipes to deal with that issue (unless they don't have that particular problem).